# Error returning validation messages in record update form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having problems checking the functioning of the validations of a form that updates the information of a certain record, apparently the validations work, but they return an error that I just had to print so you can better understand what is happening:

[Erro image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHj4Y.png)

Apparently the validations work, but the page address is not the form's, that's why the page is completely empty, just containing the validation messages.

form_update.php

```
<?php if (!empty($errors)): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
            <li><?= $error ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<form action="<?= site_url('update/'.$hxh['id_hunter'])?>" method="POST">
    <div class="form_group">
        <div class="form_group">
            <div for="name_hunter">Nome:
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_hunter" maxlength="30" value="<?= $hxh['aome_hunter'] ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form_group">
            <div for="age_hunter">Idade:
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age_hunter" onkeypress="$(this).mask('00', {reverse: true});" value="<?= $hxh['age_hunter'] ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        ...
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrows-rotate"></i>&nbsp;Update</button>
</form>
```

- `HunterController.php`

```
public function formUpdateHunter($id_hunter)
{
    try {
        $hunter = new HunterModel();
        $dados['hxh'] = $hunter->where('id_hunter', $id_hunter)->first();
        return view('form_update', $dados);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function updateHunter()
{
    try {
        helper(['form','url','html']);
        $hunter = new HunterModel();
        $id_hunter = $this->request->getPost('id_hunter');
        $dados = [
            'name_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('name_hunter'),
            'age_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('age_hunter'),
            'height_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('height_hunter'),
            'weight_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('weight_hunter'),
            'type_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('type_hunter'),
            'type_nen' => $this->request->getPost('type_nen'),
            'type_blood' => $this->request->getPost('type_blood')
        ];
        if ($hunter->update($id_hunter, $dados)){
            return $this->response->redirect(site_url('listing'));       
        } else {
            return view('form_update', ['errors' => $hunter->errors()]);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: It's not your problem, but it is good practice to correctly terminate `<?php endif ?>` and `<?php endforeach ?>` with a `;`

Comment: You are also generating some bad HTML with that code. `<li> ... </li>` should exist inside a `<ol></ol>` or `<ul></ul>` set

Comment: @RiggsFolly i inserted ```;``` in ```<?php endif ?>``` and ```<?php endforeach ?>```, but no success.

Comment: As I said, ___It's not your problem,___ in this case but

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it stops rendering the html, because in `updateHunter` the template is missing the `$hxh['id_hunter']` variable for the form's `action` attribute.

Try passing the hunter data to the template again in `updateHunter` (I only changed the `else`):

```
public function updateHunter()
{
    try {
        helper(['form','url','html']);
        $hunter = new HunterModel();
        $id_hunter = $this->request->getPost('id_hunter');
        $dados = [
            'name_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('name_hunter'),
            'age_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('age_hunter'),
            'height_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('height_hunter'),
            'weight_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('weight_hunter'),
            'type_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('type_hunter'),
            'type_nen' => $this->request->getPost('type_nen'),
            'type_blood' => $this->request->getPost('type_blood')
        ];
        if ($hunter->update($id_hunter, $dados)){
            return $this->response->redirect(site_url('listing'));       
        } else {
            $dados['id_hunter'] = $id_hunter;
            return view('form_update', ['errors' => $hunter->errors(), 'hxh' => $dados]);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to translate ```$dados``` to ```$data```, but thanks, your answer solved my problem.